# Calling a Function from Another Class

Tags: vb.net

I am a self-taught programmer in an environment whereby I don't have the luxury of checking up on best practice all the time, however in this instance I don't believe what am I doing is at all best practice and need someone to tell me otherwise if necessary.

I have my Main Class and then a SQLFunctions Class, within the Main Class I obviously do my Form Load and I also populate some DataTables.

I have a function in SQLFunctions Class that returns SQL to a DataTable for me, works fine.

My query is I am declaring this ReturnDataTable Function as

```
Public Shared Function ReturnDataTable(ByVal SQL As String)
```

Now I'm convinced this isn't the way I should be doing this, or is it? Is there another way I should be call a Function from the SQLFunctions Class from within my Main Class?

Cheers

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Well I read somewhere about not using 'Shared' Variables across your program as it doesn't initialize its own 'instance'. Plus I don't know if it has any effect on the performance of the software. Its curiosity really. I'm learning so would like to know if it is or isn't best practice.

Comment: Well, it's not a variable. IMO nothing wrong with having a set of Shared (static C#) methods in a shared class, for use through your program. Essentially what you're working towards here is a Data Access Layer - DAL - which is a pretty mainstream concept.
As an aside, if you are self-taught and haven't already read 'Code Complete' I'd recommend you get yourself a copy . . .

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  Never write code without it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ideas where to use shared versus instance methods.

Use shared when your class has no state, such as in pseudo code below:

```
' This is state-less object
Public Class UserDataAccess

    ' hide constructor to make sure no instance created
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GeAlltUsers() As List(Of User)
        ' Get all users from DB
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetUser(id As Integer) As User
        ' Get single user from DB
    End Sub

End Class
```

And use instance when your class has state, such as in pseudo code below:

```
Public Class UserRepository

    ' private members represent state of the object
    Private _dataProvider As IDataProvider ' Oracle? Sql Serv? MySql?
    Private _users As List(Of User)

    Public Sub New(dataProvider As MyDataProvider)
        _dataProvider = dataProvider
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetUsers() As List(Of User)
        If _users Is Nothing Then 
            LoadUsers() ' loads collection _users
        End If
        Return _users
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetUser(id As Integer) As User
        If _users Is Nothing Then 
            LoadUsers() ' loads collection _users
        End If
        Return _users.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.Id = id) ' This is System.LINQ extention
    End Sub

End Class
```

So, the answer is - nothing wrong with `shared` methods or classes if state is not required.